# Автозаполнение поля в админке Django на основе другого поля

Tags: django, model

Имеется модель:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Проверяемое слово',
                            default='', unique=True)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True,
                              verbose_name='Правильный ответ',
                              error_messages={'unique': 'Такое слово уже есть в базе'})
```

Оба поля будут содержать кириллицу. Хочу, чтобы в админке при заполнении поля Word автоматически заполнялось поле Answer. Автозаполнение должно работать по аналогии с prepopulated_fields с поддержкой юникода, но поддерживать символ пробела и не делать транслитерацию.
Как можно провернуть данный трюк?

Comment: Не понятна суть Вашего вопроса - автозаполнение в окне браузера, или после нажатия кнопки "Сохранить ",  на сервере?

Comment: В окне браузера в админке django

Comment: В таком случае без ajax пользовательской формы тут не обойтись. Если вкратце - Вам нужно написать свою форму и ее обработчики, в том числе ajax

Comment: Спасибо! добавил JS скрипты и все получилось!